# Samsung Ultra book won't wake up after hibernate and suspend on Crunchbang

Tags: debian, crunchbang, suspend, hibernate

I've been struggling for a few hours to get suspend and hibernate working on my [Samsung ATIV BOOK 9 Lite](http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/339341/samsung-ativ-book-np905s3g-k01nl-zwart/specificaties/). When I try to resume the screen power led goes on, but screen stays black. The capslock led doesn't react when pressing the capslock key, so increasing the brightness of the screen using the Fn keys also doesn't work.

I've used kernel versions 3.11 and 3.12rc5 and the pm logs won't tell me much.

```
$ uname --all
Linux wiske 3.11-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.11.10-1 (2013-12-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My hardware:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 983d
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 9840
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 3a)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 02)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0c)
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Last log lines from `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`:

```
$ tail -n /var/log/pm-suspend.log
+ maybe_chvt
+ is_set true
+ return 0
+ return
+ is_set no
+ return 1
+ local status=0
+ log 
+ is_set true
+ return 0
+ local fmt=%s\n
+ [  = -n ]
+ printf %s\n 

+ log -n /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video hibernate hibernate: 
+ is_set true
+ return 0
+ local fmt=%s\n
+ [ -n = -n ]
+ fmt=%s
+ shift
+ printf %s /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video hibernate hibernate: 
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video hibernate hibernate: + hook_exit_status 0
+ log success.
+ is_set true
+ return 0
+ local fmt=%s\n
+ [ success. = -n ]
+ printf %s\n success.
success.
+ LAST_HOOK=99video
+ IFS=

+ IFS=  

+ inhibited
+ [ -f /var/run/pm-utils/pm-suspend/storage/inhibit ]
+ return 0
+ date
+ log Tue Dec 10 22:52:08 CET 2013: performing hibernate
+ is_set true
+ return 0
+ local fmt=%s\n
+ [ Tue Dec 10 22:52:08 CET 2013: performing hibernate = -n ]
+ printf %s\n Tue Dec 10 22:52:08 CET 2013: performing hibernate
Tue Dec 10 22:52:08 CET 2013: performing hibernate
+ sync
+ do_hibernate
+ [ -n  ]
+ echo -n disk
```

How can I enable suspend and/or hibernate on my CrunchBang installation?

Comment: I apologize for asking the obvious, and I'm on desktop, but I suspend and need to press the power button to wake up. Just making sure you're saying that's what you do and you get a black screen with the leds on?

Comment: I pushed my power button in order to wake up.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem on my Samsung Chronos 7 laptop in Ubuntu. You can check if it's the same problem by doing the following (this exact commands are working in Ubuntu, maybe you need a bit of adaptation for your system):

1) go to a virtual console (`ctrl-alt-F1`)

2) do the login there

3) try to suspend with the command `sudo /sbin/pm-suspend` (you will be asked your password or root password) or using the key-combo to suspend if any

4) resume. If the system come back, then try `ctrl-alt-F7` to go back to your  graphical environment.

If it works, then you can automate the switch, see https://askubuntu.com/a/355532/16395.

On a side note, on my system nothing worked correctly without adding `radeon.dpm=1` on the kernel boot options list. YMMV...

Comment: Unfortunately my system doesn't resumes,, so Im stuck at step 4.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is not supported by a wide amount of laptops so desactived on Ubuntu 12.04 for example, don't expect miracles with a device not made for Linux at first ...

Comment: 'deactived' sounds like 'it is in there, but not enabled'. In that case I must be possible to reactivate it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem running Crunchbang Waldorf on a Lenovo S10-3. I upgraded to Sid and now suspend and resume work fine. (I don't know about hibernate).